# Add onInterceptTouchEvent() to inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, touch-event

I have a linear layout existing of an EditText and an ImageView.
When I click anywhere inside the linear layout I need a touch event to be dispatched to this layer, but the EditText is blocking/consuming the touch event.

I want to use onInterceptTouchEvent(ev MotionEvent) but I can't figure out how to set it on the linear layout.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/consultCv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
         android:layout_width="@dimen/grid_3x"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_3x"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:src="@drawable/img_document" />

         <EditText
         style="@style/TextStyle.EditDisabled"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_1x"
         android:text="@string/document" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

```
class ArchiveActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)
    }
}
```

I tried to override onInterceptorTouchEvent() in this activity but it can only be overridden in a view.

Is there a way to treat my linear layout as a view and then implement this as a lambda expression?
Do I need to tear apart my XML file and then rebuild every separate view group in code?

My linear layout is inside a layout with several layers, so I can't just make a view out of it alone.

Help me Obi Wan Kenobi, you'r my only hope!

Comment: Why do you need a TouchEvent on a LinearLayout containing an EditText? Are you going to use the EditText (as you want to catch the touch events)? Otherwise replace your EditText by a TextView, problem solved.

Comment: @Eselfar Its a part of a profile view.
When the user press an &quot;edit button&quot; the edit text fields are set to isEnabled = true. When the user have entered a url into the field and press save, the field is disabled and the whole area Including the text an image and some padding should open the url.
Is there another (better) way to do this?

Comment: Yes. You can use a [ViewSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) which contains a TextView and an EditText. First it displays a TextView, if the user press the `edit` button you 'switch' the view to the EditText. When it's done, you set the text entered by the user to the TextView and switch back to it.

Comment: @Eselfar that sounds amazing! I'll give it a try after lunch and come back with a big upvote if it works.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Eselfar I forgot to get back to you, but it worked!
Thanks for the help.